# Create Akka Dispatcher programmatically

Tags: scala, akka, dispatcher

I have a scenario where I create actors on demand. I want to be able to define a `Dispatcher` and attach it to my actor programmatically.

The deal is: My `ActorSystem` is already running, which mean that it have already loaded all the `Akka` configurations.

Seems like the `Dispatcher` has to be defined in the `application.conf` before creating the `ActorSystem`, so I have two questions:

1. Is there anyway to add new `Akka` configuration to an `ActorSystem` after it has been started?
2. Is there another way to use `Props[MyActor].withDispatcher("any-dispatcher")` without the `Dispatcher` being defined in the `ActorSystem` configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the dispatchers must be configured when the actor system is started, they can not be defined dynamically.

If you have an app where you can restart the actor system the config library has options to programmatically define blocks, so you could generate a config based on the default one and then pass that config to the `ActorSystem` when you create it.